# How do I link multiple TFS 2012 Build Definitions into a single build definition

Tags: tfs, build-automation

How do I or can I, create a hierarchy of build definitions in TFS 2012?

I currently have a master build script (.cmd) that calls multiple child scripts (.cmd).
I want to migrate this to the TFS build system and maintain the hierarchy.

I can't seem to figure out if this is possible using the TFS 2012 build system.

Here's what I'm talking about:
MasterBuildScript.cmd
call componentscript1
call componentscript2
call componentscript3
call ...
call packaging routine for all components

componentscript1.cmd
build solution componenta1
build solution componenta2
build solution componenta3
...

componentscript2.cmd
build solution componentb1
build solution componentb2
build solution componentb3
...

more components...

Is there a way to do this with the standard TFS 2012 Build Definitions?
- Bruce

Comment: Sure it is possible to call multiple build definitions from within a master build definition by writing custom code/activity. But what exactly are you try to acheieve? If your CMD files are just compiling the solution files, why do you want to keep using them? Are you doing these child scripts to take care of dependencies or something else? What is the situation that is forcing you to keep multiple build definitions? Explain in detail!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without doing any custom coding. You will have to make a minor addition to a build process template, however. That doesn't use code, it uses Windows Workflow Foundation.

Essentially, you would need to setup TFS Team Build definitions for each .cmd build script that you currently have. One for the master build, one for each component build. The real work involved here is converting your .cmd script into a TFS build definition.

Then, to auto queue the "child" builds, you can edit the process template for your master build definition and add an "InvokeProcess" activity  - this lets you shell out to the command line as part of the build process. You can use the command line utility TFSBuild.exe to kick off the "child" builds. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337622(v=vs.90).aspx

I've used something similar in the past where I have a build for my core set of assemblies. That build then kicks off all of the builds which have dependencies on those assemblies.

Comment: Yes you can do this by using the InvokeProcess and just calling the CMD script, and I do know that. But the solution you have mentioned comes with lot of cons. Lets say, you created a build defintion which just calls the CMD scripts, then you absolutely dont have any control over what is happening from TFS. You are spawning off a new process which runs off on it's on. If you want to stop a build which is running, then if you just stop the build in TFS it wont stop it. The batch file would still be running. This is just one exmple.

Comment: Thats why I wanted to know his root problem and then suggest a solution. Just running CMD scripts from TFS build def is not the best solution.

Comment: Calling the existing .cmd scripts from within the build definition was not what I was suggesting. You're right, that's a terrible idea. Re-reading my response I can see how you might have interpreted it that way. Those .cmd scripts need to be converted into TFS build definitions which perform the same work as the original .cmd script. The only thing the InvokeProcess activity should be used for is kicking off the "child" builds via TFSBuild.exe.